# Invalid initialization of reference in C++

Tags: c++, function, data-structures, compiler-errors

So I am trying to compile so I can run my first function to see if it is working properly but I keep getting these errors. Please help! I get the errors:

*"invalid initialization of reference of type 'Division&' from expression of type 'char'"*

I also get "*In passing argument 1 of `void Create_Corporate_File(Division&, Division&, Division&, Division&)'"*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 12;


struct Division
{
char divName [SIZE];
double sales [4];
};

int main()
{
char Div_E; 
char Div_W; 
char Div_N; 
char Div_S;

void Describe_Program ();
void Create_Corporate_File (Division& Div_E, Division& Div_W, Division& Div_N, Division& Div_S);
//void Display_Corporate_Sales (Div_E, Div_W, Div_N, Div_S);


Describe_Program(); 
Create_Corporate_File (Div_E, Div_W, Div_N, Div_S);


system ("PAUSE");
return 0; 
}


void Describe_Program()
{ 
cout << "This program will prompt you to enter the sales amount\n";
     << "for each quarter of the North, South, West and East Division.\n";
     << "After you enter the sales amount for each quarter, the program\n";
     << "will be able to calculate the total quarterly sales for that";
     << "division"; 
     <<endl<endl; 
     return; 
} 

void Create_Corporate_File (Division& Div_E, Division& Div_W, Division& Div_N, Division& Div_S)
{
 fstream quarterly_sales; 
 quarterly_sales.open ("quarterly_sales.dat" ios::out|ios::binary)

     For(div = 0, div < 4, div++)
     {
           Division temp;

     if (div == 0)
                  temp = Div_E;
     else 
          if (div == 1)
                  temp = Div_W;
          else 
               if (div == 2)
                  temp = Div_N;
               else 
                  temp = Div_S;

                   cout << "Please enter the division: "; 
                    cin.getline (temp.divName, SIZE); 

      For(sales = 0, sales < 4, sales++)
      {         
cout << "Please enter the sales amount for quarter " << sales + 1 <<":\n";
cin >> temp.sales [sales]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `char Div_E;` to `Division Div_E;` and so on.

Comment: You have many other errors in your code (btw).

Answer (score 1):

Div_E and so on are of type char, while Create_Corporate_File() function expects type Division & as the arguments - change the type to that.